# Playwright pipeline endless loading

Tags: azure, playwright, playwright-test

Hiall,

I developed a ui test with playwright.
I run this in azure pipeline, when a test is pass, everything is OK, the
steps:
run test - pass
publish artifact - pass
post job - pass
but when i add an error to the test -
await expect(activitiesHeader).toHaveClass("goodclass badclass")
I get an error in pipeline log, it is ok, and reach the timeout too
but the pipeline is stuck  in run test step (so the next steps never execute)

my yaml:

- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
  versionSpec: '14.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'
- script: npm install
- script: npm ci
- script: npm install @playwright/test
- script: npx playwright install --with-deps
  displayName: "Install browser dependencies"
- script: npm i playwright-chromium

  displayName: "run the test"
  condition: succeeded()
- script: npm run azurelogin
- task: CopyFiles@1
  condition: succeededOrFailed()            # Run task even if previous ones fail
  inputs:
  #leave it empty, the copying is done from the root folder
  #sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/_daniavander_hydro-test/playwright-report'
  contents: |
  playwright-report/**
  screenshot/**
  test-results/**
  targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
  PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'